# Are eldritch blasts with essences applied considered different abilities with regard to metamagic feats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, metamagic

I've been searching and searching, and I cannot find a clear answer to this question:

If I take Maximize Spell-Like Ability and apply it to "Eldritch Blast," giving me 3 casts per day of maximized "Eldritch Blast," and I apply an eldritch essence, for example turning the blast into "Brimstone Blast," am I allowed to maximize the "Brimstone Blast" or is it no longer the same spell-like ability?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of Eldritch Blast (Sp) states:

> If you apply a blast shape or eldritch essence invocation to your eldritch blast...

This text suggests that blast shapes are applied to the Eldritch Blast, they are not independent SLAs. This is supported by other text in the description of Eldritch Blast:

> ...the feat Ability Focus (eldritch blast) increases the DC for all saving throws (if any) associated with a warlock’s eldritch blast by 2.

Since the basic Eldritch Blast has no DCs associated with it, we can only conclude the authors are referring to EBs modified by blast shapes and essences.

Therefore, the spell-like ability being used is still Eldritch Blast, even when Brimstone Blast is applied to it. So your Maximize SLA feat works just fine.

Comment: Can you provide a better citation of RAW, rather than quoting something that doesn't really get your point across?

Comment: I’m away from my  books, but I could swear I remember some statement about Ability Focus (*eldritch blast*) (or maybe it was Ability Focus (invocations) for all of them) that might be used as a solid precedent to strengthen this answer.

Comment: @KRyan found it, added to answer.

Comment: @Zangief updated the question with another rules quote, if you found that one unconvincing.

Comment: I'm not sure saying "this one feat seems to work, therefore all similar feats should work" is a convincing argument, especially when the other feats are in the same book (on the same page in this case) and it is not called out. I feel they would have made it a lot more clear if invocations were simply associated with Eldritch Blast rather than replacing it.

Comment: The description of Brimstone Blasts states very explicitly:

"This eldritch essence invocation allows you to change your _eldritch blast_ into a _brimstone blast_.  A _brimstone blast_ deals fire damage . . ."

Ergo, it is no longer "eldritch blast" -- it is now "brimstone blast."  Since it explicitly changed it in the description of the brimstone blast invocation, it makes me think you cannot maximize it unless you take maximize spell-like ability for brimstone blast specifically.

Comment: That seems good enough for me, but I also feel like the rules are directly contradicting each other there.

Comment: Welcome to D&D! We do our best to untangle conflicting rules, but sometimes all you can do is make your case and see how it goes.

Comment: Considering that this is somewhat ambiguous, and this is not tagged [[tag:rules-as-written]] anyway, it would improve this answer to discuss the balance considerations for ruling one way or the other. The warlock is a rather weak class, so it certainly seems to me that multiplying its feat taxes is a very bad idea.

Comment: @KRyan If warlocks had to take another feat for every blast shape, they could Maximize their blasts 6, 9, 12...etc times per day instead of just 3. I am not sure which ruling is actually more powerful.

Comment: @SPavel Oh hm, I forgot you weren’t allowed to re-choose the same SLA for more uses per day on that SLA. Still, raising the discussion as a consideration for the DM in making a ruling is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

From my reading of *Brimstone Blast*, it **changes** *Eldritch Blast* into *Brimstone Blast*, so would require a separate *Maximize Spell-like Ability* feat.

> This eldritch essence invocation
>   allows you to change your *eldritch blast*
>   into a *brimstone blast*.{...}

-*Complete Arcane* page 132

Comment: Considering that this is somewhat ambiguous, and this is not tagged [[tag:rules-as-written]] anyway, it would improve this answer to discuss the balance considerations for ruling one way or the other. The warlock is a rather weak class, so it certainly seems to me that multiplying its feat taxes is a very bad idea.

Comment: Though, as @SPavel points out, the balance consideration is not that straightforward, since *eldritch blast* and *brimstone blast* being separate also implies you get to choose something *eldritch blast*-like for multiple copies of the feat, allowing you to use the feat more than you would otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't like to try and work out the balance either way, though I feel it's less powerful having a small collection of meta-abilities rather than a few uses of any meta-ability (similar to sorcerer vs wizard spells, wizard is stronger because they have a bigger toolkit to work with). But as I say, it's a muddy problem and I'd probably stick with what I perceive to be RAW in this case,

Answer (score 0):

No, it is still modifiable by the [Maximize Spell-Like Ability] Feat.

The Brimstone Blast augments the Spell-Like Ability Eldritch Blast to deal 2d6 fire damage. It does not change the effect type from Spell-Like to anything else. You may perform the [Maximize Spell-Like Ability] Feat with the newly augmented [Brimstone] Eldritch Blast (and subsequently deal the maximum 12 fire damage when striking and the maximum 12 fire damage when caught on fire).

Comment: Maximize Spell-like Ability *et al.* require that you choose one spell-like ability for it to work with. The question is not whether *brimstone blast* makes *eldritch blast* no longer eligible for Maximize Spell-like Ability in general, but rather whether or not you need to take Maximize Spell-like Ability twice, once for *eldritch blast* and again for *brimstone eldritch blast*.

Comment: @KRyan has a good point. "This eldritch essence invocation allows you to change your eldritch blast into a brimstone blast." That specific language says X becomes Y. It doesn't say X becomes X+Y.